# How to make glow/bloom effect around a simple circle?

Tags: 2d, glsl, shader, bloom

I do a simple circle in fragment shader:

```
float dist = length(gl_PointCoord - 0.5); // distance to center
float circle = smoothstep(0.3, 0.5, dist); // apply smoothing curve
```

And now I would do some bloom effect around it. Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIS2o.png

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a **Radial Gradient**. 
This link looks helpful [RadialGradient Shader](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source:-Radial-Gradient-Shader)

Answer (score 0):

Please find this nvidia [document](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/opengl/src/simple_glow/doc/simple_glow.pdf) for the simple glow effect. The basic idea is to

1. render the scene in the back buffer activate the effect
2. render some elements of the scene in a FBO
3. compute the Glow effect
4. bind the final FBO as a texture and blend this effect with the previously rendered scene in the backbuffer

Comment: There is an example with bitmap, but I guessing it should be easier for just circle.